# When can we characterize Sobolev space $W^{2k,p}(\Omega)$ only via the Laplacian-like terms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

One of the characterizations of the fractional Sobolev space $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ uses the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$:

> $f \in W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ iff $f$ is a tempered distribution such that $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left( (1 + \lvert \xi \rvert^s )\mathcal{F}(f) \right) \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

The $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left( \lvert \xi \rvert^s \mathcal{F}( \cdot) \right)$ part would be interpreted as the fractional Laplacian $(-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}$ and should agree with $(-\Delta)^k$ (defined as the usual differential operator) for $s=2k$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
This way, if I understand correctly, makes it so that for $s \in \mathbb{N}$ the norm of $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left( (1 + \lvert \xi \rvert^s )\mathcal{F}(f) \right)$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is equivalent to the usual norm $\sum_{\lvert \alpha \rvert \le s } \lVert \partial^\alpha f \rVert_{L^p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Let $s =2k$, where $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. We can then define space
$\widetilde{W}^{s,p}(\Omega)$ as the completion of $C^{\infty}(\Omega) \cap W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ in the norm given by $\lVert f \rVert_{L^p(\Omega)} + \lVert (-\Delta)^k f \rVert_{L^p(\Omega)}$.

While this space may not necessarily be equal to $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$, by multiplying elements of $\widetilde{W}^{s,p}(\Omega)$ by appropriate functions from $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ one could prove that elements of $\widetilde{W}^{s,p}(\Omega)$ should be at least in $W^{s,p}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$.

I would like to know whether there is a characterization of $\Omega$ such that the spaces $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ and $\widetilde{W}^{s,p}(\Omega)$ are, in fact, equal, with equivalent norms.

Comment: If there is a boundary, the two spaces are usually different. On harmonic functions, indeed, one looses any control of the derivatives near the boundary. The typical situation is the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$: on the functions $z^n$ the "tilde" norm cooincides with the $L^p$ one.